# add user to active directory group sometimes does not working

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, powershell, call

i am using in django the function call imported from subprocess to run powershell script. this script receiving an username as argument and adding it to active directory group. there is something weird, no errors, and it's not working. but if i run it manually it sometimes working and sometimes not working. im really confused and need your help.
python line running the PS script:

```
    call(["powershell", "{0} {1}".format(powershell_script_path, username)])
```

returns no error.
and the powershell script:

```
    $username=$args[0]
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "some_group" -Members $username
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: I have occasionally had issues adding members to groups. When I do it this way I have never had a problem: `Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "some_group" -Members (Get-AdUser $username)`

Comment: i tried that but i still have that weird problem that sometimes the script adding the user is working, and sometimes not..

Comment: And there are still no errors? I have had flaky issues in the past with AD cmdlets, but there have always been errors. I would try doing some explicit error checking around the command. Also perhaps a try{} catch{} block.